# Calling `super()` in parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

I'm reading Raymond Hettinger's [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)  About a page in, there's this example:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, shapename, **kwds):
        self.shapename = shapename
        super().__init__(**kwds)        

class ColoredShape(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, **kwds):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(**kwds)

cs = ColoredShape(color='red', shapename='circle')
```

Why is it necessary to call `super()` in `Shape` here?  My understanding is that this calls `object.__init__(**kwds)` since `Shape` implicitly inherits from `object`.

Even without that statement, we've already

- established `shapename` already in the parent's `__init__`,
- established the child class's `color` in an explicit method override,
- then invoked the parent's `__init__` with `super()` in `ColoredShape`.

As far as I can tell, dropping this line produces the same behavior & functionality:

```
class Shape:  # (object)
    def __init__(self, shapename, **kwds):
        self.shapename = shapename
        # super().__init__(**kwds)

class ColoredShape(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, **kwds):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(**kwds)
    def check(self):
        print(self.color)
        print(self.shapename)

cs = ColoredShape(color='red', shapename='circle')

cs.check()
# red
# circle
```

What is the purpose of `super()` within `Shape` here?

Comment: I think it is only example how to send arguments from one class to other using `**kwds` and remove `shapename` from  `**kwds` - and `Shape` parent is not important in this example. Maybe `Shape` should have parent but it is not main element in all example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see that @user2357112 has already provided a correct answer. I was working on an example that I'd though I'd leave here because it's pretty much what user2357112 is describing.  Consider a mixin class like this:

```
class PositionMixin:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, **kwds):
        super().__init__(**kwds)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Let's say you apply that to your `ColoredShape` class:

```
class ColoredShape(Shape, PositionMixin):
    def __init__(self, color, **kwds):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(**kwds)
```

If `Shape` doesn't call `super.__init__`, then when you do this:

```
myshape = ColoredShape('red', shapename='circle', x=1, y=1)
print(myshape.x, myshape.y)
```

You get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "supertest.py", line 18, in <module>
    print (myshape.x, myshape.y)
AttributeError: 'ColoredShape' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The call to `super.__init__` in shape is necessary to call the `__init__` method on `PositionMixin`.

Comment: Thanks, reading up on [diamond rule](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#multiple-inheritance-the-diamond-rule).  Is it easy to explain why `super().__init__()` in `shape` knows to reference `PositionMixin` (sibling) rather than `object`'s (parent) `__init__()`?  Or should I just take this as is and acknowledge I don't know MRO very well at all?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you.  I mean, the short answer is that `Shape` doesn't "know" anything; the call to `super()` returns a proxy object pointing at the appropriate class higher up in the MRO, and `Shape` is just operating on that.  But that's a little handy wavy, and I don't know the gritty details of how Python objects are constructed to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 10):

The point is cooperative multiple inheritance. The point of the whole entire article is cooperative multiple inheritance, really.

You look at `Shape` and you don't see any parents besides `object`. Sure, but that doesn't mean there aren't any siblings, or anything else on the MRO after `Shape`. `super()` isn't just for superclasses; it searches for the next implementation of the method in the [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). For example, one of the later classes in the article is

```
class MovableColoredShape(ColoredShape, MoveableAdapter):
    pass
```

In this case, `Shape.__init__` needs to call `super().__init__`, or `MoveableAdapter.__init__` and all further `__init__` calls will be skipped.